# Threading + Recursion (takes 1 positional argument but 39 were given)

Tags: python-3.x

Guys I am trying to create a spider however i keep getting the error  : TypeError: file_thread() takes 1 positional argument but 39 were given
which is so weird as it takes a list and is given a list

```
        import sys
        sys.path.insert(0, "/media/user/Data/Programming/Projects")
        import re , threading , bs4 , async_lib , urllib.request

        file_lock=threading.Lock()
        spider_lock=threading.Lock()


        def file_thread(data):
            file_lock.accquire()
            print('IO Operation')
            async_lib.WriteAsync('spider.txt',data,).start()
            file_lock.release()


        def Get_Links(webpage):
            byte_html=urllib.request.urlopen(webpage).read()
            bad_html= byte_html.decode()
            html = str(bs4.BeautifulSoup(bad_html))
            all_links = re.findall('href="(http.*?)"',html)
            return all_links

        def spider_logic(raw_links):
            for link in raw_links:
                try:
                    links = Get_Links(link)
                    t1 = threading.Thread(target=file_thread,args=link).start()
                    t1 = threading.Thread(target=file_thread,args=links)
                    spider_lock.accquire()
                    print(links)
                    t2 = threading.Thread(target=spider_logic, args=links).start()
                    spider_lock.release()
                except:
                    pass


        def main():
            startup='http://www.myegy.to'
            links = Get_Links(startup)
            spider_logic(links)


        if __name__=='__main__':
            main()
```

Comment: Try ``import pprint`` and ``pprint.pprint()`` your ``link`` and ``links`` or  check type by calling ``print(type())`` on your variables to make sure they are in format you expect. It is possible one of them is a tuple and not a list.

Answer (score 4):

What you pass into `args` in `Thread()` is expected to be iterable. When you pass in a string, it iterates over each character and treats it as a separate arg. You should instead pass it in as a tuple.

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=file_thread,args=(links,))
```